# Access violation at address 055E1C10. Read of address 055E1C10.

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Всем привет! Уважаемые программисты, можете подсказать с чем может быть связана ошибка при закрытии delphi 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С кривостью Delphi :)
Если возникает каждый раз, значит, что-то криво встало, пробуйте переустановить. Если работаете в Win Vista/7/8, возможно, Delphi нужны права администратора. Если бывает не каждый раз, то просто не обращайте внимания, это не лечится. Еще могут кривые сторонние компоненты гадить.

Comment: Эх.. Печаль.. Но спасибо)